# Keep getting i/o error 1117 while trying the file operations

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, io

I am trying to copy a huge file (around 50 GB) to external hard drive. I keep getting the I/O error. I tried all things compressing the file, trying to copy to same drive splitting the file using HJSplit. While splitting I got more specific error "I/O Error 1117". What does this error means and how can I recover this file? I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/O Error 1117 is the very unwelcome harbinger of hardware failures. What is especially troubling, in your case, is that it is not obvious whether the error message refers to your external disk, or to your internal disk.

To shed more light on the matter, I suggest you run this command

```
chkdsk <volume drive letter> /r /f
```

on each drive you have, until you find the culprit. When you issue the command, you will be asked whether you wish to schedule the check at next boot (if the disk to be checked is the internal one); you should reply yes, turn the pc off and on, and then expect the check to take even a few hours, in the case of very large partitions.

At this point you will know more about the location of the disk failure, the diagnosis, and from that you can start planning a prognosis.